# htaccess rule to server JSON file form folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How I can show a JSON file while accessing a URL. I have this JSON file in a folder in my web root. Is it possible to show this JSON file using htaccess rules. My URL is as follows

http://example.com/api/v1/entity

I have api/v1/entity folder structure in my webroot

Can I place this static attributes.json file in the entity folder and on hitting the URL http://example.com/api/v1/entity how can I show the JSON data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your file inside `api/v1/entity/` and name it for example `myfile.json`.

Create a new file `api/v1/entity/.htaccess` with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ myfile.json [L]

# return application/json for myfile.json
<Files "myfile.json">
   ForceType application/json
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, the problem was in my .htaccess file
I tried to change

```
 # Deny accessing extensions listed below
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
</Files>
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

To

```
# Deny accessing extensions listed below
<Files ~ "(.lock|.git)">
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
</Files>
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

Actually removing the .json extension works fine.